# Script to remove Exchange 2010 AutoMapping for all mailboxes

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, powershell, outlook-2010, outlook-2007

I have an Exchange 2010 SP3 server that's getting Application event error 9646 from MSExchangeIS:

Mapi session [ID] [AD User] exceeded the maximum of 500 objects of type "objtFolder"

Looking into this, the cause was found to be several users that have a lot of Full Access Permissions on other people's mailboxes.

Because of the way this changed in SP1 [See Technet article HERE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh529943%28v=exchg.141%29.aspx), They now automatically open all the users they have access to, rather than being able to add or open them only when needed.

Ideally, I'd like a script I can run to globally remove the -Automapping $true string for all users: This should leave them access to the mailbox when needed, but stop it from automatically opening, taking up MAPI sessions.

I tried the Microsoft Technet Script from the above URL, but that didn't appear to work as intended:

```
[PS]$FixAutoMapping = Get-MailboxPermission sharedmailbox|where {$_AccessRights -eq "FullAccess" -and $_IsInherited -eq $false}
The operation couldn't be performed because object sharedmailbox couldn't be found on '[Servername]'.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-MailboxPermission], ManagementObjectNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : B485A4C7,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RecipientTasks.GetMailboxPermission
```

I'm presuming that sharedmailbox is a specific example mailbox which Doesn't exist on my server: I need a script that searches through all the mailboxes, then changes Automapping $true to Automapping $false for any access permissions on the mailbox.

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is incredibly easy. You simply need to retrieve a list of mailboxes and run the example against each of them:

```
# Get all mailboxes in the forest
$Mailboxes = Get-Mailbox -ResultSize unlimited -IgnoreDefaultScope
$ConfirmPreference = 'None'

# Iterate over each mailbox
foreach($Mailbox in $Mailboxes)
{
    try 
    {
        # Try to run the example fix against the current $Mailbox
        $FixAutoMapping = Get-MailboxPermission $Mailbox |where {$_.AccessRights -eq "FullAccess" -and $_.IsInherited -eq $false}
        $FixAutoMapping | Remove-MailboxPermission
        $FixAutoMapping | ForEach {Add-MailboxPermission -Identity $_.Identity -User $_.User -AccessRights:FullAccess -AutoMapping $false} 
    }
    catch
    {
        # Inform about the error if unsuccessful
        Write-Host "Encountered error: $($Error[0].Exception) on mailbox $($Mailbox.DisplayName)" -ForegroundColor Red
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the script. I Don't use powershell much, so I assume I save it as a.ps1 file, then call it from the powershell command line?

Comment: Or you can just copy and paste in to an Exchange PowerShell window. Possibly followed by an additional Enter or two.

Comment: Exactly :-) You might need to change the [Execution Policy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176961.aspx) in order for it to execute as a script

Comment: Thanks, Mathias - the script worked, apart from you had to press a (Yes to all) for every user. For future use, is there a way yes to all can be added to the script?

Comment: Yes by setting the `$ConfirmPreference` or append `-confirm $false` to the `Remove-MailboxPermission` statement

Comment: -confirm $false and that script worked perfectly. Thank you @mathias-r-jessen for the answer, and thanks for the assist Longneck.